# What's the voltage between series of voltage source and current source?

Tags: current-source, voltage-source, open-source

[image]

I'm confused with the voltage between point a and point b. Did the Vab only depend on the voltage source or i should consider the current source to sum it up?

Comment: The resistance between a and b nodes is infinite. So, what would be the voltage drop across an infinite resistance when the flowing current is not zero? Also remember that a current source has an infinite internal resistance.

Answer (score 0):

> *I'm confused with the voltage between point a and point b. Did the Vab
> only depend on the voltage source or i should consider the current
> source to sum it up?*

The 1 amp current source has to force 1 amp from node (b) to node (a) hence, given that it appears to be an open circuit, the voltage between node (a) and node (b) is infinite. The voltage source is of no relevance here.

Comment: then what if the current source is also parallel with other resistors, independent or dependent source? does we can find the Vab using superposition or source transformation? or it still have infinite values?

Comment: @dan if the current source is parallel with finite valued resistors then the current source terminal voltage is finite. That defines the voltage at node (b) then, if we assume the common connection between voltage source and current source is regarded as 0 volts then we can also say what voltage is at node (a). Then the voltage difference is (a) minus (b). No need for source transformation or superposition in this simple circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the basics: what is an ideal constant current source? It's a device that outputs such **voltage**, that the current out of it is some fixed value. In your case, it generates such voltage, that the current out of it should be 1A.

My definition of ideal constant current source is my simple interpretation, there are many ways to word it, but the idea is similar, for example, look at [this](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Ideal-current-source.php) or [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/ideal-voltage-source#:%7E:text=An%20ideal%20current%20source%20is,the%20voltage%20across%20the%20source.) or [this](https://electricalbaba.com/ideal-practical-current-source-explained/).

The problem is, that you have no closed circuit - no complete path for charges to flow. No matter how much voltage the current source generates, it's never enough to provide 1A of current. It's always 0. So voltage at *b* is infinite. It always tries to output more, but it's never enough to make 1A.

Now, imagine you put a 1 Ohm resistor between *a* and *b*. And this problem makes a lot more sense. Current source outputs whatever voltage is needed to source 1A. In this case, 1A across 1 Ohm resistor would mean 1V voltage difference across Rab, and therefore voltage at *a* is 4V, and voltage at *b* is 5V, because it has to be above *a*, the current must go left.

The question without any resistor between *a* and *b* doesn't really make much sense, you may have overlooked something in the task or forgot some detail. It makes a lot more sense if there is some resistor in there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm still finding the way to understanding the basic theory and the explanation actually helps me :)

Comment: @dan if answer or comment is helpful, upvote it, if it ultimately answered your question, select it as an answer, this will close your question (unless you want to keep it open and wait for input of someone else, which is also ok)